# Why the columns are different colored?

Tags: html, css

I've made a table from divs, and I want that every second row is different colored. But every columns are different colored. What is the problem?

```css
.mTable {
  display: table;
  width: auto;
  background-color: #eee;
  border: 1px solid #666666;
}

.mTableRow {
  display: table-row;
  width: auto;
  clear: both;
}

.mTableHeading {
  display: table-header-group;
  background-color: #ddd;
  height: auto;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
}

.mTableCell,
.mTableHead {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #999999;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.mTableRow>div:nth-child(even) {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="mTable">
  <div class="mTableRow">
    <div class="mTableHead">ID</div>
    <div class="mTableHead">Név</div>
    <div class="mTableHead">Komment</div>
    <div class="mTableHead">Tól</div>
    <div class="mTableHead">Ig</div>
  </div>
  <div class="mTableRow">
    <div class="mTableCell">9</div>
    <div class="mTableCell">Robi1 </div>
    <div class="mTableCell"> </div>
    <div class="mTableCell">null</div>
    <div class="mTableCell">null</div>
    <div class="mTableCell"><button class="w3-button w3-round-xxlarge w3-aqua">Választom</button></div>
  </div>
  <div class="mTableRow">
    <div class="mTableCell">31</div>
    <div class="mTableCell">FŰTÉS </div>
    <div class="mTableCell">Hőszivattyú teremhőmérsékletek</div>
    <div class="mTableCell">null</div>
    <div class="mTableCell">null</div>
    <div class="mTableCell"><button class="w3-button w3-round-xxlarge w3-aqua">Választom</button></div>
  </div>
  <div class="mTableRow">
    <div class="mTableCell">36</div>
    <div class="mTableCell">Növényház</div>
    <div class="mTableCell">Sablon komment</div>
    <div class="mTableCell">null</div>
    <div class="mTableCell">null</div>
    <div class="mTableCell"><button class="w3-button w3-round-xxlarge w3-aqua">Választom</button></div>
  </div>
  <div class="mTableRow">
    <div class="mTableCell">93</div>
    <div class="mTableCell">Üvegház</div>
    <div class="mTableCell">Sablon komment</div>
    <div class="mTableCell">null</div>
    <div class="mTableCell">null</div>
    <div class="mTableCell"><button class="w3-button w3-round-xxlarge w3-aqua">Választom</button></div>
  </div>
  <div class="mTableRow">
    <div class="mTableCell">94</div>
    <div class="mTableCell">Cserepes fűtés-hűtés</div>
    <div class="mTableCell">2017 február 9.-i állapott</div>
    <div class="mTableCell">null</div>
    <div class="mTableCell">null</div>
    <div class="mTableCell"><button class="w3-button w3-round-xxlarge w3-aqua">Választom</button></div>
  </div>
  <div class="mTableRow">
    <div class="mTableCell">95</div>
    <div class="mTableCell">Cserepes 2017</div>
    <div class="mTableCell">Sablon komment</div>
    <div class="mTableCell">null</div>
    <div class="mTableCell">null</div>
    <div class="mTableCell"><button class="w3-button w3-round-xxlarge w3-aqua">Választom</button></div>
  </div>
  <div class="mTableRow">
    <div class="mTableCell">96</div>
    <div class="mTableCell">3 fő helyiség</div>
    <div class="mTableCell">Sablon komment</div>
    <div class="mTableCell">null</div>
    <div class="mTableCell">null</div>
    <div class="mTableCell"><button class="w3-button w3-round-xxlarge w3-aqua">Választom</button></div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: That you did not apply :nth-child to the actual row elements, but the divs inside them, d’oh? You want `.mTableRow:nth-child(even) > div`

Comment: With your css you color every even cell inside your rows, which results in the blue columns.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just your css was wrong replace with this:

```
.mTableRow:nth-child(even) div {
    background: blue;
}
```

```css
.mTable {
  display: table;
  width: auto;
  background-color: #eee;
  border: 1px solid #666666;
}
.mTableRow {
  display: table-row;
  width: auto;
  clear: both;
}
.mTableHeading {
  display: table-header-group;
  background-color: #ddd;
  height: auto;
  color : black;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
}
.mTableCell, .mTableHead {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #999999;
  text-align: center;
  color : black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.mTableRow:nth-child(even) div {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="mTable">
    <div class="mTableRow">
        <div class="mTableHead">ID</div>
        <div class="mTableHead">Név</div>
        <div class="mTableHead">Komment</div>
        <div class="mTableHead">Tól</div>
        <div class="mTableHead">Ig</div>
    </div>
    <div class="mTableRow">
        <div class="mTableCell">9</div>
        <div class="mTableCell">Robi1 </div>
        <div class="mTableCell"> </div>
        <div class="mTableCell">null</div>
        <div class="mTableCell">null</div>
        <div class="mTableCell">
            <button class="w3-button w3-round-xxlarge w3-aqua">Választom</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="mTableRow">
        <div class="mTableCell">31</div>
        <div class="mTableCell">FŰTÉS </div>
        <div class="mTableCell">Hőszivattyú teremhőmérsékletek</div>
        <div class="mTableCell">null</div>
        <div class="mTableCell">null</div>
        <div class="mTableCell">
            <button class="w3-button w3-round-xxlarge w3-aqua">Választom</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="mTableRow">
        <div class="mTableCell">36</div>
        <div class="mTableCell">Növényház</div>
        <div class="mTableCell">Sablon komment</div>
        <div class="mTableCell">null</div>
        <div class="mTableCell">null</div>
        <div class="mTableCell">
            <button class="w3-button w3-round-xxlarge w3-aqua">Választom</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="mTableRow">
        <div class="mTableCell">93</div>
        <div class="mTableCell">Üvegház</div>
        <div class="mTableCell">Sablon komment</div>
        <div class="mTableCell">null</div>
        <div class="mTableCell">null</div>
        <div class="mTableCell">
            <button class="w3-button w3-round-xxlarge w3-aqua">Választom</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="mTableRow">
        <div class="mTableCell">94</div>
        <div class="mTableCell">Cserepes fűtés-hűtés</div>
        <div class="mTableCell">2017 február 9.-i állapott</div>
        <div class="mTableCell">null</div>
        <div class="mTableCell">null</div>
        <div class="mTableCell">
            <button class="w3-button w3-round-xxlarge w3-aqua">Választom</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="mTableRow">
        <div class="mTableCell">95</div>
        <div class="mTableCell">Cserepes 2017</div>
        <div class="mTableCell">Sablon komment</div>
        <div class="mTableCell">null</div>
        <div class="mTableCell">null</div>
        <div class="mTableCell">
            <button class="w3-button w3-round-xxlarge w3-aqua">Választom</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="mTableRow">
        <div class="mTableCell">96</div>
        <div class="mTableCell">3 fő helyiség</div>
        <div class="mTableCell">Sablon komment</div>
        <div class="mTableCell">null</div>
        <div class="mTableCell">null</div>
        <div class="mTableCell">
            <button class="w3-button w3-round-xxlarge w3-aqua">Választom</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need

```
.mTableRow:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #ccc;
}

.mTableRow:nth-child(even) {
  background: blue;
}
```

as

```
.mTableRow>div:nth-child(even) {
  background: blue;
}
```

selected the even numbered **children** of each `.mTableRow` rather than the row itself.

```css
.mTable {
  display: table;
  width: auto;
  background-color: #eee;
  border: 1px solid #666666;
}

.mTableRow {
  display: table-row;
  width: auto;
  clear: both;
}

.mTableHeading {
  display: table-header-group;
  background-color: #ddd;
  height: auto;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
}

.mTableCell,
.mTableHead {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #999999;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
  width: 200px;
}

.mTableRow:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #ccc;
}

.mTableRow:nth-child(even) {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="mTable">
  <div class="mTableRow">
    <div class="mTableHead">ID</div>
    <div class="mTableHead">Név</div>
    <div class="mTableHead">Komment</div>
    <div class="mTableHead">Tól</div>
    <div class="mTableHead">Ig</div>
  </div>
  <div class="mTableRow">
    <div class="mTableCell">9</div>
    <div class="mTableCell">Robi1 </div>
    <div class="mTableCell"> </div>
    <div class="mTableCell">null</div>
    <div class="mTableCell">null</div>
    <div class="mTableCell"><button class="w3-button w3-round-xxlarge w3-aqua">Választom</button></div>
  </div>
  <div class="mTableRow">
    <div class="mTableCell">31</div>
    <div class="mTableCell">FŰTÉS </div>
    <div class="mTableCell">Hőszivattyú teremhőmérsékletek</div>
    <div class="mTableCell">null</div>
    <div class="mTableCell">null</div>
    <div class="mTableCell"><button class="w3-button w3-round-xxlarge w3-aqua">Választom</button></div>
  </div>
  <div class="mTableRow">
    <div class="mTableCell">36</div>
    <div class="mTableCell">Növényház</div>
    <div class="mTableCell">Sablon komment</div>
    <div class="mTableCell">null</div>
    <div class="mTableCell">null</div>
    <div class="mTableCell"><button class="w3-button w3-round-xxlarge w3-aqua">Választom</button></div>
  </div>
  <div class="mTableRow">
    <div class="mTableCell">93</div>
    <div class="mTableCell">Üvegház</div>
    <div class="mTableCell">Sablon komment</div>
    <div class="mTableCell">null</div>
    <div class="mTableCell">null</div>
    <div class="mTableCell"><button class="w3-button w3-round-xxlarge w3-aqua">Választom</button></div>
  </div>
  <div class="mTableRow">
    <div class="mTableCell">94</div>
    <div class="mTableCell">Cserepes fűtés-hűtés</div>
    <div class="mTableCell">2017 február 9.-i állapott</div>
    <div class="mTableCell">null</div>
    <div class="mTableCell">null</div>
    <div class="mTableCell"><button class="w3-button w3-round-xxlarge w3-aqua">Választom</button></div>
  </div>
  <div class="mTableRow">
    <div class="mTableCell">95</div>
    <div class="mTableCell">Cserepes 2017</div>
    <div class="mTableCell">Sablon komment</div>
    <div class="mTableCell">null</div>
    <div class="mTableCell">null</div>
    <div class="mTableCell"><button class="w3-button w3-round-xxlarge w3-aqua">Választom</button></div>
  </div>
  <div class="mTableRow">
    <div class="mTableCell">96</div>
    <div class="mTableCell">3 fő helyiség</div>
    <div class="mTableCell">Sablon komment</div>
    <div class="mTableCell">null</div>
    <div class="mTableCell">null</div>
    <div class="mTableCell"><button class="w3-button w3-round-xxlarge w3-aqua">Választom</button></div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your columns are different because of this:

```
.mTableRow>div:nth-child(even) {
 background: blue;
}
```

This is colouring every column at `even` index to `blue`.
And on of your heading is missing.

```css
.mTable {
  display: table;
  width: auto;
  background-color: #eee;
  border: 1px solid #666666;
}

.mTableRow {
  display: table-row;
  width: auto;
  clear: both;
}

.mTableHeading {
  display: table-header-group;
  background-color: #ddd;
  height: auto;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
}

.mTableCell,
.mTableHead {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #999999;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.mTableRow>div:nth-child(even) {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="mTable">
  <div class="mTableRow">
    <div class="mTableHead">ID</div>
    <div class="mTableHead">Név</div>
    <div class="mTableHead">Komment</div>
    <div class="mTableHead">Tól</div>
    <div class="mTableHead">Ig</div>
    <div class="mTableHead">Missing</div>
  </div>
  <div class="mTableRow">
    <div class="mTableCell">9</div>
    <div class="mTableCell">Robi1 </div>
    <div class="mTableCell"> </div>
    <div class="mTableCell">null</div>
    <div class="mTableCell">null</div>
    <div class="mTableCell"><button class="w3-button w3-round-xxlarge w3-aqua">Választom</button></div>
  </div>
  <div class="mTableRow">
    <div class="mTableCell">31</div>
    <div class="mTableCell">FŰTÉS </div>
    <div class="mTableCell">Hőszivattyú teremhőmérsékletek</div>
    <div class="mTableCell">null</div>
    <div class="mTableCell">null</div>
    <div class="mTableCell"><button class="w3-button w3-round-xxlarge w3-aqua">Választom</button></div>
  </div>
  <div class="mTableRow">
    <div class="mTableCell">36</div>
    <div class="mTableCell">Növényház</div>
    <div class="mTableCell">Sablon komment</div>
    <div class="mTableCell">null</div>
    <div class="mTableCell">null</div>
    <div class="mTableCell"><button class="w3-button w3-round-xxlarge w3-aqua">Választom</button></div>
  </div>
  <div class="mTableRow">
    <div class="mTableCell">93</div>
    <div class="mTableCell">Üvegház</div>
    <div class="mTableCell">Sablon komment</div>
    <div class="mTableCell">null</div>
    <div class="mTableCell">null</div>
    <div class="mTableCell"><button class="w3-button w3-round-xxlarge w3-aqua">Választom</button></div>
  </div>
  <div class="mTableRow">
    <div class="mTableCell">94</div>
    <div class="mTableCell">Cserepes fűtés-hűtés</div>
    <div class="mTableCell">2017 február 9.-i állapott</div>
    <div class="mTableCell">null</div>
    <div class="mTableCell">null</div>
    <div class="mTableCell"><button class="w3-button w3-round-xxlarge w3-aqua">Választom</button></div>
  </div>
  <div class="mTableRow">
    <div class="mTableCell">95</div>
    <div class="mTableCell">Cserepes 2017</div>
    <div class="mTableCell">Sablon komment</div>
    <div class="mTableCell">null</div>
    <div class="mTableCell">null</div>
    <div class="mTableCell"><button class="w3-button w3-round-xxlarge w3-aqua">Választom</button></div>
  </div>
  <div class="mTableRow">
    <div class="mTableCell">96</div>
    <div class="mTableCell">3 fő helyiség</div>
    <div class="mTableCell">Sablon komment</div>
    <div class="mTableCell">null</div>
    <div class="mTableCell">null</div>
    <div class="mTableCell"><button class="w3-button w3-round-xxlarge w3-aqua">Választom</button></div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```html
<style type="text/css">
 .TFtableCol{
  width:100%; 
  border-collapse:collapse; 
 }
 .TFtableCol td{ 
  padding:7px; border:#4e95f4 1px solid;
 }
 /* improve visual readability for IE8 and below */
 .TFtableCol tr{
  background: #b8d1f3;
 }
 /*  Define the background color for all the ODD table columns  */
 .TFtableCol tr td:nth-child(odd){ 
  background: #b8d1f3;
 }
 /*  Define the background color for all the EVEN table columns  */
 .TFtableCol tr td:nth-child(even){
  background: #dae5f4;
 }
</style>

<table class="TFtableCol">
 <tr><td>Text</td><td>Text</td><td>Text</td><td>Text</td></tr>
 <tr><td>Text</td><td>Text</td><td>Text</td><td>Text</td></tr>
 <tr><td>Text</td><td>Text</td><td>Text</td><td>Text</td></tr>
 <tr><td>Text</td><td>Text</td><td>Text</td><td>Text</td></tr>
</table>
```